# JPA query to retrieve data by multiple columns according one criteria

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Hello I have entities mapped to each other like this.
Property Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "properties")
public class Property extends BaseStatusAuditEntity {

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "property")
    private List<Inventory> inventory;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "property")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Transaction> transaction;

}
```

Inventory Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "inventory")
public class Inventory extends BaseStatusAuditEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    private Property property;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "inventory")
    private List<Transaction> transaction;
}
```

And lastly Transaction Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
public class Transaction extends BaseStatusAuditEntity {
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Property> property;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Inventory> inventory;
}
```

I have query to retrieve transaction by property, but it only gets data strictly only transaction property, as you can see inventory have property as well. I want to run query to get data from Transaction where property matches property and inventory property matches property given by me.
My query looks like this.

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Transaction AS t JOIN t.property p WHERE p IN ?1 AND t.createdAt BETWEEN ?2 AND ?3 ")
List<Transaction> getAllByPropertyAndDatesBetweenGroupedByTransactionType(List<Property> property, Date dateFrom, Date dateTo);
```

How to retrieve data where transaction property is in property array and aswell data where transaction inventory property is in property array.

Comment: You have to tell spring data that you need properties from inventory properties to be considered as well. It will not assume that you need that

Comment: How to achieve this in my query? I know what I need to do but I do not know how....

Comment: Try this `getAllByPropertyAndDatesBetweenAnd Inventory_PropertyGroupedByTransactionType(List<Property> property, Date dateFrom, Date dateTo, List<Property> property)`